# SVN Copy is not working

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am using below command to copy from trunk to a branch.

`svn copy http://sicsbatchdev.milli.com/svn/sics/Milli-Re Migration New/trunk \ http://sicsbatchdev.milli.com/svn/sics/Milli-Re Migration New/branches/MSLD_4 \`

Running the above command , i am getting -
svn: E200007: Cannot mix repository and working copy sources

I tried many ways by removing spaces and other thing but still copy command is not working .. Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

- You have to put the URLs in quotes because there are whitespaces. That's why the Subversion client can't parse the URLs.
- If you are on Windows, use `^` instead of `\`.